# Delete Mysql record using array

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to delete multiple record(s) by using codeigniter

```
$this->db->delete() and $this->db->where()
```

I want to delete record(s) with an array like

```
$id =array(
  0=>'13',   //13 is the id
  1=>'4',    //4 is the id
  2=>'2'     //2 is the id
);
```

The array was generated by the users so it will be dynamic. 
I just want to know if codeigniter can take the array as a option in delete method.

According to this. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

array won't work in the following method.

```
$this->db->delete()
$this->db->where('id', $id); //I don't think I can do this.
```

I could use foreach to loop but it seems to me there are better ways. I was wondering if anyone could help me about it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really familiar with codeigniters active record but I believe the stmt you would like is:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM tbl WHERE id IN (".implode(',',$idsToDelete.");";
$this->db->query($sql);
```

This might work better with active record:

```
$this->db->where('IN ('.implode(',',$idsToDelete).')', NULL, FALSE);
$this->db->delete();
```

Comment: You can chain your actions: $this->db->where('IN ('.implode(',',$idsToDelete).')', NULL, FALSE)->delete()

Answer (score 1):

The method where really accept an array as parameter?

I think your source code should look:

```
$this->db->delete()
$this->db->where($id['i_index']);
```

Answer (score 0):

This post is dated, but I figured still deserves the best/right answer:

```
    $this->where_in('id', array(13, 4, 2))->delete('db_table_name');
```